# Error No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python

what is the problem with this code I am using python 2.7.2
I am trying to create a python script that can automatically look up the lyric for a song it is for a project I have been working on

```
import codecs
import json
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2

import bs4  

def extract_lyrics(page):
    """Extract lyrics text from given lyrics.wikia.com html page."""
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page)
    result = []
    for tag in soup.find('div', 'lyricbox'):
        if isinstance(tag, bs4.NavigableString):
            if not isinstance(tag, bs4.element.Comment):
                result.append(tag)
        elif tag.name == 'br':
            result.append('\n')
    return "".join(result)

artist = raw_input("Enter artist:")
song = raw_input("Enter song:")

query = urllib.urlencode(dict(artist=artist, song=song, fmt="realjson"))
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?" + query)
data = json.load(response)

if data['lyrics'] != 'Not found':

    print(data['lyrics'])

    lyrics = extract_lyrics(urllib2.urlopen(data['url']))
    filename = "[%s] [%s] lyrics.txt" % (data['artist'], data['song'])
    with codecs.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        output_file.write(lyrics)
    print("written '%s'" % filename)
else:
    sys.exit('not found')
```

it gives me this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elaya\Desktop\Song.py", line 26, in <module>
    data = json.load(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

please help me

Comment: Have you inspected the `response` variable to see if it actually returns json at all

Answer (score 1):

You should look at what the response actually is. When I try that URL with those parameters, I get a mediawiki help page; reading through, it seems that you need to supply an `action` parameter with the value of `lyrics`.

```
query = urllib.urlencode(dict(action='lyrics', artist=artist, song=song, fmt="realjson"))
```

Comment: thanks so much you saved my project I really don't know how to thank you