# Swift: Unable to parse JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

The service is working just fine when I check:
[http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?func=getSong&artist=Tom+Waits&song=new+coat+of+paint&fmt=json](http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?func=getSong&artist=Tom%20Waits&song=new%20coat%20of%20paint&fmt=json)

But when I try it in Swift my data reads "233 bytes".

Anyone know what is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
func getWikiaInfo(completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    let url = URL(string: "http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?func=getSong&artist=Tom+Waits&song=new+coat+of+paint&fmt=json")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        // no error, woohoo!
        if error == nil {

            // there was data returned
            if let data = data {

                let parsedResult: [String:AnyObject]!
                do {
                    parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                } catch {
                    print("Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'")
                    return
                }

                print(parsedResult)
                    completionHandler(true, nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/41183709/1187415

Comment: Thanks guys. I found my answer. It is not real JSON.

Comment: See the duplicate link Martin posted. I provide a complete answer to the exact same question on that other thread, including a different query that DOES produce JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your **API Json data is not valid to parsing**.Even online parser also can't able to parse your API data.check below image.

[image]
[image]